# How can I modify the state a work item is changed to after PR?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

When we create a pull request and link a work item, after the PR is completed the status of the work items are automatically changed to "invalid". How can we change that behavior to a different status?

Answer (score 4):

In a recent update to Azure DevOps, you can now [customize work item state when pull request is merged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-176-update#customize-work-item-state-when-pull-request-is-merged).

> When you create a PR, in the description, you can set the state value
> of the linked work items. You must follow the specific syntax.
>
> `{state value}`: #ID When you merge the PR, the system reads through
> the description and updates the work item state accordingly. In the
> follow example we set work items #300 and #301 to Resolved, #323 and
> #324 to Closed.
>
> [image]

Comment: this is interesting. Is it not possible to set the _Default_ state though? since it is changing it to invalid by default (also noting that we have custom states -- and I can test currently that this will work with them)

Comment: Have you customized the states or transitions?

Comment: How do I customize the transitions ? (there are custom states, such as for example "Ready for QA" -- and I cannot use that state in this way, I have just tested it)

Answer (score 2):

The [Set work item state in pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/add-links-to-work-items?view=azure-devops#set-work-item-state-in-pull-request) feature is also works for custom states. Here is my sample:

1. Add a custom state to task.
   [image]
2. Create a new pull request and add the Description like:

   Ready for QA: #id

[image]

3. Create pull request and complete the merge. Do not check "Complete linked work items after merging" option.

[image]

4. Now, the status of my task has been updated to Ready for QA.

[image]

In addition, the product group is still improving this feature. If you have any concern or suggestions, you can share it in this [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365704/customize-work-item-state-after-pr-is-closed.html) and [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1200823/ability-to-configure-target-work-item-state-after.html).

Comment: I tried to test this based on the earlier answer, but did not think to account for step 3.. will test and revise this answer shortly.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help.